# How to Un-Domain Join Azure VMs from Acive Directory on VM Deletion?

Tags: powershell, azure

I have an Azure JSON template that uses the `JsonADDomainExtension` extension to automatically join VMs to the domain when they are created. We have a Service Account that is used to perform the domain join.

My question is - what is the best way to remove the VMs from the domain when a VM needs to be deleted?

Should I write a PowerShell script to un-domain join a VM and then delete it? If so, can someone point me to the appropriate PowerShell commands?

Comment: yes, you should write a powershell script for that

Comment: What I ended up doing was adding a lock to prevent deletion called Unjoin domain. with a note. That tells the person what they need to do before deleting the resource, whether they do it manually or with a PS script is now irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I write a PowerShell script to un-domain join a VM and then
>   delete it?

We can use [Azure VM Custom Script Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/extensions-customscript) to Unjoin Domain.

About `custom script extension`, we can use powershell like this:

```
# create vm object
$vm = Get-AzureVM -Name 2016clas -ServiceName 2016clas1313

# set extension
Set-AzureVMCustomScriptExtension -VM $vm -FileUri myFileUri -Run 'create-file.ps1'

# update vm
$vm | Update-AzureVM
```

About unjoin domain, we can use this command [Remove-computer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-computer?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), like this:

```
Remove-Computer -UnjoinDomaincredential Domain01\Admin01 -Passthru -Verbose -Restart
```

After that, we can use powershell to [Remove-AzureRmVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/remove-azurermvm?view=azurermps-4.2.0) Azure VM:

```
Remove-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup11" -Name "VirtualMachine07"
```